Is Windows 365 a full Windows operating system?
If I have software installed on Windows (say, Windows 10), can I install it on Windows 365?  For example, Matlab, Anaconda, Cygwin [1] (which can run X-windows on top of Windows), etc.?  What about running VMware or VMware-like software like VirtualBox or Docker daemons and servers?  Or software that controls multiple cores, like Spark (or PySpark) [2]?
The closest thing I can find is here: "Apps that worked on Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 also work on Windows 365. If you experience issues with your apps, Microsoft will help you fix them at no cost with an eligible subscription."
However, different apps require support by the OS at different levels.  I'm hoping that there is more concrete and specific information than a very simple high-level assertion on promotional page.  For example, some experience that people have had with some complex software requiring deep OS support.  The assurance that Microsoft will fix incompatibilities may inspire confidence after having established a track record of resolving problems arising from some of the more complex software.
P.S. I looked around for an ideal Stack Exchange, and there is no ideal one.  The next best one is Server Fault, but that's for back end management of cloud servers.  I'm asking from the user perspective.  I am open to suggestions.
Notes
[1] I'd also be curious about whether WSL can run on Windows 365.
[2] I realize that one can chose the number of CPUs for Windows 365, but I wonder whether this actually refers to the number cores (and whether they might be multithreading cores).  For such performance-focused usage, I also found information about Microsoft Dev Box, but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for.  The environment seems highly geared to MS development environments, in which case I'd still be looking at Windows 365's ability to host more generic development tools.  I'm more interested in a vendor-agnostic analytics environment, on an exploratory basis in addition to the sometimes development of deployment ready tools.  At the mature end, cloud accounts may help with deployment of some such tools.
